# Get Current Selected Item of Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, android-menu, navigation-drawer

How can i get Current selected item of navigation drawer? My menu is stored in **drawer_menu.xml**

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.change_sec:
                    Intent intent_sec = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ClassDataProvider.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent_sec, 9);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
                case R.id.holiday_list:
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HolidayList.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your code should work, what's happening?

Answer (score 12):

For example, you can use:

```java
private int getCheckedItem(NavigationView navigationView) {
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
        if (item.isChecked()) {
            return i;
        }
    } 

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find out if an item is current selected with this:

```
if(navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_item).isChecked())
//do some stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got `OnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, with method `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`, which is called every time new item is selected. This `item` has methods `getItemId()` which will return id, and get `getOrder()`, which will return position.

Create `int` var in your class, save this id.

For example you can save it to bundle later on `onSaveInstanceState`, then get it back on `onRestorInstanceState`. And apply it using `navigationView.setCheckedItem(savedItemId);`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I always mantain a global reference to the nav controller like this on my MainActivity:

```
navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

If I need to know on which menu item my user is currently I just get the current destination's id like this:

```
val menuId = (activity as MainActivity).navController.currentDestination?.id
```

You can compare the menuId with the defined ids at your navigation graph (which are the same ids you should have for your menu items).