# Update currently highlighted fragment in nav drawer

Tags: java, android

When I open a new fragment from the nav drawer it correctly highlights it but when I press the back button it doesn't update the highlighted element so I was thinking of using `navigationView.setCheckedItem();` but that needs an int and I have no clue on what to put there since I have no idea if I can use the back stack somehow or not.

At the moment onBackPressed only has

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I solved by doing one of the worst things I could have imagined, in **each fragment**:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    auIsInFront = true;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    auIsInFront = false;
}
```

And then in **MainActivity**:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (isInFront){
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        }else if (standardIsInFront){
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_standard);
        }else if (auIsInFront){
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_au);
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's horrible but that's the only thing that I could think of

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView#setcheckeditem) says setCheckedItem takes view id as argument. You should use it like this:

```
navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.yourMenuItem);
```

Now You want to create some variable that keeps last activity / menu item and then change highlith. Example:

```
int lastMenuID;
public void onBackPressed() {
  DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
      drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }else{
      int thisID = /*[this menu item]*/;
      navigationView.setCheckedItem(lastMenuID);
      lastMenuID = thisID;
      super.onBackPressed();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah but how do I get to know the current menu item after the back button has been pressed?

Comment: How do I initialize thisID if I have no clue on what activity is beign displayed at the moment?

Comment: You can use function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336538/get-current-selected-item-of-navigation-drawer-in-android